# Simplify song and artist names

Tags: python, neural-network, spotify

### Introduction

Hello. I am currently building a web application that takes a random song and put it into a `spotify` playlist. (The user can't choose which songs he wants)

So I search the input with the `spotify api` and get a list of results.

### Problem

Since `spotify` is returning not always the best result, I wanted to loop through the results and find the best matching one. How would you achieve the best result?

#### My attempt

The first thing I tried, was matching the strings with the `fuzzywuzzy` library.
This looked something like this:

```py
song_ratio = ratio(real_song_name,result_song_name)
```

This was good and it helped a lot but what is with songs that just have a different punctuation?

So what I did is removing the punctuation with:

```py
song_name = song_name.translate(str.maketrans('', '', punctuation))
```

I want also want to avoid Karaoke, Remastered or Live Versions, etc. e.g.:
*Stay with Me Till Dawn - Live in the UK, 1982 / 2010 Remaster from Judie Tzuke*
Just filtering by this names would make no sense because they appear not in the same shape.

Another problem:
Searching for the song "Fascination" from "Jane Morgan And The Troubadors"

What I get is:

```
Best found song: Its Been A Long Long Time to 22 % match<br>
Best found artist: Jane Morgan 54 %
```

Would I just have queried for the song "Fascination" from "Jane Morgan" i would get:

```
Best found song: Fascination 100 % <br>
Best found artist: Jane Morgan 100 %
```

### Question

What is a good way to solve this issue? Is it possible to train a `neural network` to process my strings into the right format and then find the best matching?

Comment: If the user is to enter the song and artist, you could just display a list of results and let them choose which one to select

Comment: @Peter thank you for your comment. The way I described it in my question is not exactly how my application works. I tried not to make it more complex. Long story short the user can't select the song they want. I will edit my question.

Comment: I don't know too much about this stuff, but I reckon your best bet would be to rely on their search, as they'll have paid millions to develop exactly what you're trying to do. Theirs might not work in every case, but I don't think yours would either (eg. if you fix one issue, it might cause another).

Answer (score 0):

Something you could try is to use the [advanced query syntax](http://web.archive.org/web/20120704131650/http://www.spotify.com/us/about/features/advanced-search-syntax/) offered by Spotify search, and only search for part of the song title/artist name. For example your query for "Fascination" from "Jane Morgan And The Troubadors" could become:

> artist:"Jane Mo" track:"Fascin"

and still return the correct result.
This query looks for the exact string 'Jane M' appearing in the artist name and 'Fascin' in the track title.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I actually did not thought of anything like that and I think this might be the answer to my problem. According to which procedure would you cut the string then? Just simply cut 30 % of the string?

Comment: Probably there's no ideal cutoff for all situations, but maybe you can split by words and only retain the first couple of words from an artist name/song title?